# What's the first aired episode where we hear the Borg say "resistance is futile"?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification, borg

IIRC the first episode we see them in is TNG's *Q Who* when Q throws the *Enterprise* into another quadrant to prove to Picard that they aren't ready for what's out there, but I don't recall whether they said "Resistance is Futile" in that episode​.

To emphasize, I'm looking for the first occurrence of "Resistance is Futile" in episode airing order (in any of the *Star Trek* shows/films), not timeline order. So we don't have to worry about that *First Contact* storyline. :-)

Comment: Dr who aired the line resistance is futile back in 1977 the Master said it to The Doctor!

Comment: Not the Borg and not the exact phrasing. But Spock says "Any show of resistance would be futile" in Star Trek: The Motion Picture (1979), which predates the appearance of the Borg by nearly 10 years.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Star Trek: The Next Generation* Season 3 Episode 26, [Best of Both Worlds, Part 1](https://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/174.txt):

> PICARD: I have nothing to say to you, and I will resist you with my last ounce of strength.
>
> BORG: Strength is irrelevant. **Resistance is futile.** We wish to improve ourselves. We will add your biological and technological distinctiveness to our own. Your culture will adapt to service ours.

Comment: The scripts are online. Wow!

Comment: Everything is online, my friend.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder even YOU are online.